# CallableTaskletAdapter Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

Does CallableTaskletAdapter use a separate thread than the step itself?

```
    @Bean
    public Callable<RepeatStatus> callableObject() {

        return () -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("This was executed in another thread");

            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public CallableTaskletAdapter tasklet() {
        CallableTaskletAdapter callableTaskletAdapter =new CallableTaskletAdapter();

        callableTaskletAdapter.setCallable(callableObject());

        return callableTaskletAdapter;
    }
@Bean
    public Step callableStep() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("callableStep")
                .tasklet(tasklet())
                .build();
    }
```

Running this code prints the thread name as "**main**" in callable tasklet. Which means it is not using the new thread. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does CallableTaskletAdapter use a separate thread than the step itself?

No, it does not use a separate thread. It [calls](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/a7092a21e428cf904f210aff2682b518dc3649c5/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/CallableTaskletAdapter.java#L64) `Callable#call` using the thread executing the tasklet.

Comment: So, is this synchronous in nature then ? What is the benefit of using `CallableTaskletAdapter` then over writing the logic in our custom class which implements the `Tasklet` interface ?

Comment: I don't think this adapter was designed for concurrency. The idea is to adapt an existing `Callable` (or probably a `Callable` that is defined in a library you do not control) to a tasklet.